# Deviare2 hook WriteFile API twice for only one write

Tags: c#, api, hook, writefile, apimonitor

Deviare2 is a professional API Hook Library on MS Windows. It's easy use and powerful. But when I want to hook `WriteFile` using a C# dummy writer ,I found it hooked `WriteFile` twice. I try to use API Monitor to hook dummy writer, I found API Monitor just hook one for every write call. That's strange!

hook code:

```
spyMgr = new NktSpyMgr();
        
NktProcess _process = GetProcess("DummyWriter.exe");

while (_process == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("wait for process start...");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    _process = GetProcess("DummyWriter.exe");
}
        
hookDllGetClassObj = spyMgr.CreateHook("kernel32.dll!WriteFile", (int)(eNktHookFlags.flgOnlyPreCall));

hookDllGetClassObj.Attach(_process, true);

hookDllGetClassObj.Hook(true);
hookDllGetClassObj.OnFunctionCalled += OnDllGetClassObjectCalled;
```

dummy write:

```
string key = "";

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    int index=1;
    while (key == "")
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("d:\\dummy.txt",true))
        {
            string str = string.Format("{0}:oh gotcha!", index);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            sw.WriteLine(str);
            index++;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
});

key = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

The APIs are not hooked twice but the callback is called two times. One before the original API is called and then after.

You must check the `NktHookCallInfo` parameter and see if you are in the pre or postCall so you can do modifications to parameters and result.

BTW: Deviare InProc is the engine that does a more classic hooking style.

Comment: I have add a eNktHookFlags.flgOnlyPreCall flag when I create the hook like : hookDllGetClassObj = spyMgr.CreateHook("kernel32.dll!WriteFile", (int)(eNktHookFlags.flgOnlyPreCall)); Is it necessary to check it again in the hook callback?

Comment: I checked it ,all twice hooked are preCall